# Is it possible to match, and negate, a single control character with POSIX basic regex?

Tags: regex, posix

I know you can do this by using escape characters like \t\n etc, using some forms of regex, but I don't think these are valid with BRE. So is this just not possible with BRE or is there some way of specifying these characters that I'm not aware of?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK \t\n are valid control charachters in POSIX BRE

Comment: Well I spent a while searching google, but couldn't seem to find any page mentioning \t\n which was specifically referring to BRE. Also, even if they are valid, they are not valid within bracket expressions.